# The continuity of a two-variable function and its derivative

Tags: calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

[image]

In this question,

1. There's a corresponding value of f at (0,1), so we can say that f has a limit at (0,1) does it correct?
2. f is not continuous at (0,1) so we can't do derivative,so (B) & (C) are incorrect?
3. The equation in (D) is correct no matter it is continuous or not ?

So the answer of this question is (A)(D)?

Comment: What happens if you take the path $x=y-1$? Also your conclusion that "D is correct no matter what" is wrong. This is only true if the function is differentiable.

Comment: The limit of the function at $(0,1)$ (if it exists) is not affected by the value at $(0,1)$, so your reasoning for (A)  is incorrect.
Have you already shown that f is not continuous at $(0,1)$? also, partial derivatives may exist even if the function is not differentiable.
The equation in (D) is correct if the function is differentiable at that point.

Comment: It is same with $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(0,0)$.